# approach to keep history of JSON document changes

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I am using the `mongodb` database, therefore all documents are in `JSON` format. My current task is to somehow track a history of `document` changes. I have found out that there is an acknowledged [rfc 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) standard for this purpose, but how do you generate such array difference (i.e. difference =`patch`) in `PHP`? Or alternatively - how do I keep the JSON history of changes, maybe using other standards or approaches?

Original aproachis: Imagine that we have an Array1 which is changed. Result is array2. Then I calculate the difference (patch) using the above mentioned standard and save it in history collection in mongodb. Therefore we only save what was changed and not the whole new array.

I need to be able to save history and to restore the `document` to original state in the times of need. Here is the page I have found: http://jsonpatch.com/

Which lead to multiple libraries for `PHP` (I am using version 7). This first library generates `patch` (difference JSON which I am seeking), but this lib is also broken to the point that this `patch` can not be used!

https://github.com/mikemccabe/json-patch-php

These other libraries are using `patch` parameter but they do not generate it!

https://github.com/xp-forge/json-patch

https://github.com/gamringer/JSONPatch

So I am left with no other options at this point.

Comment: Normally I would look for an audit feature on the database instead of building it myself. That way the database itself logs all changes, including those that do not go through your script.